# routing debugging .net core api endpoint getting 404 error

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, visual-studio-debugging

I have to debug a .net core api version 3.0 but I am not sure why it is not hitting the breakpoint in the controller.
startup.cs

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
    }
```

Then in the controller I have very basic method that I need to hit

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ApplicationController : ControllerBase
{
    
    [HttpGet, Route("ping")]
    public IActionResult ping()
    {
        return Ok(DateTime.Now);
    }
 }
```

I have set it up in the project properties like this below: [image]

but when I go in Postman and try to send the GET request to http://localhost:50233/controller/ping I am getting 404 response. Same when I try with http://localhost:50233/ping I get 404 error. Where does the net core 3.0 maps the routing or what should be the route for me to hit the breakpoint please.

Comment: Have you tried `http://localhost:50233/application/ping` ?